# Error in add_shortcode when try add the shortcode to a wordpress page

Tags: wordpress-shortcode

Can somebody help me with this code i wrote. When i add the shortcode to a WordPress page i get an error when trying to save the page.

```
add_shortcode('bonnummer_1', function(){

global $wpdb; 
// this adds the prefix which is set by the user upon instillation of wordpress
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wpdatatable_2";
$current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
// this will get the data from your table
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE userid = $current_user_id" );

foreach ( $retrieve_data as $retrieved_data ){

echo $retrieved_data->projectnaam;
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
function bonnummer_1_shortcode_fun(){

    global $wpdb; 

    // this adds the prefix which is set by the user upon instillation of wordpress
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix."wpdatatable_2";

    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();

    // this will get the data from your table
    $retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM ".$table_name." WHERE userid = '".$current_user_id."'" );

    foreach ( $retrieve_data as $retrieved_data ){

        echo $retrieved_data->projectnaam;
    }

}
add_shortcode('bonnummer_1', 'bonnummer_1_shortcode_fun');
```